# How to modify port in .Net framework web api

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-framework-version

I write a demo program, to use .NET Framework Web Api2. For some reason, I have to use .NET Framework rather than .Net Core.
But I've got a problem, how to modify the port? It's always  57518. I want to change it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that you are using IIS Express, right?

In this way you need to execute the following steps:

1. In the Solution Explorer, right-click on the Project and select Properties. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UH2G.png).
2. Now the property window will be open.
3. Select the "Web" tab, check the "Override Application Root URL" Radio Button and enter the URL with your specific port (https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4mU6.png).

Now your web api will run in the informed URL.

Answer (score 2):

In Asp.NetCore WebApi application you can change port for webapi in VisualStudio "launchsettings.json" file.

[image]

Comment: Though useful, it is not the correct answer to the question.